# Searching for Files by Date modified and listing the relative dir

Tags: bash, unix

I need to find all files from within a parent directory and list the relative path from the parent dir.

Example : 
ParentDir : export/home/user/

File path : export/home/user/workspace/tmp/file1.txt

Expectation : workspace/tmp/file1.txt

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please, read how to [write a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example a.k.a. MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mansuro I tried grep which returns the file names fine but i need the entire path leading upto the file name

Comment: What about `find`?

Comment: @Mansuro Yes I am taking a look at it right now. Except it finds the file names within a parent dir. I need to prefix it with the path leading upto it.

Answer (score 0):

```
find export/home/user/ -printf "%P\n"
```

Take a look at  -printf "%p\n" too, and at the default output.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this snippet which solves my problem just fine.

```
$find -type f -mtime -1 /export/home/user/
```

Utility Describe::

mtime -1 : Finds files modified within a day.

mtime +1 : Finds files modified more than a day ago.

Hope this helps. Thanks for all your suggestions.